# How can we connect from server to mysql using paramiko?

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, paramiko

We should connect to mysql in the following way:

1. Connect using ssh to global server
2. Connect from global to local server using ssh
3. Connect to mysql using command "mysql –p" or "mysql --local-infile=1 -p"

Is there a way to do all this stuff without putty or similar tools, but using python script. I find how to connect to local server using paramiko:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=user,port = password, password=secret, key_filename=path)

vmtransport = ssh.get_transport()
vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)

jhost = paramiko.SSHClient()
jhost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
jhost.connect(hostname=dest_addr[0], username=user, password=secret, sock=vmchannel,
              key_filename = second_file_path)
```

after i connect to local how can i connect to mysql from it, using only password or i can only connect directly to mysql, using tonnel?